# Invalid XML Signature when adding namespace

Tags: digital-signature, xml-namespaces, xml-signature

I'm generating a XML Xades signature. I need to add the namespace http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2# in the TAG signature.

If I add this TAG after signing the doc, I get invalid signature error.

I don't know how to add it before, because I only have the TAG Signature after signing.´

This is the code to add namespace

```
void addNamespace(doc)
{

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");

    Node a = nl.item(0);

    Element sig = (Element)a;

sig.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:etsi","http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#");

}
```

The code for signature:

```
signContext = new DOMSignContext(pk, parentElement);
signContext.putNamespacePrefix("http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#","etsi");
XMLSignature signature;
signature.sign(signContext);
addNamespace(doc);
```

The XML:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
```

<**ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Signature-830342"**>

```
 <ds:SignedInfo Id="SignedInfo-830342">
 <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
 <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
 <ds:Reference URI="">
 <ds:Transforms>
 <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
 </ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>tKDaVHCywRrFbblaDIKZjUviXkI=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#SignedProperties-830342">
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>M/coSDm1tqC4DKkbCyXUP82fB58=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#KeyInfo-830342">
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>pInn5xZepngScAKAse0zZPuhyNU=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>

<ds:SignatureValue Id="SignatureValue843847">
PTJj6kXgDNRwXKQvDH5xr+FF5+naKjAo3bl70Wwlc6MAU2EgMTaCnh7Ml7wvfKvNWbPvTL+5bXYH FlSuC3PsDn2SguQ1vvWm1xI6cZAKh0w4sMiQiS9UDjxIifyZZqNwcZ7uCX2c6K+S7xNQZzcPi5HW oQ+6Pq8vtSZODxN6b0Y=
</ds:SignatureValue>

<ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyInfo-830342">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
MIIDiTCCAnGgAwIBAgIBKjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBsMQswCQYDVQQGEwJFUzESMBAGA1UECBMJ QmFyY2Vsb25hMQ8wDQYDVQQKEwZpc2lnbWExFzAVBgNVBAMTDmlzaWdtYSByb290IENBMR8wHQYJ KoZIhvcNAQkBFhBpc2lnbWFAaXNpZ21hLmVzMB4XDTE0MDUzMDA4MjgxOFoXDTE5MDUyOTA4Mjgx OFowgZsxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkVTMRIwEAYDVQQIEwliYXJjZWxvbmExEjAQBgNVBAcTCUJhcmNlbG9u YTEPMA0GA1UEChMGaXNpZ21hMQswCQYDVQQLEwJpdDETMBEGA1UEAxMKRGVtb3MgdXNlcjESMBAG A1UEBRMJMTIzNDU2NzhaMR0wGwYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFg5pbmZvQGlzaWdtYS5lczCBnzANBgkqhkiG 9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAl+AvFwUL16YdzlPT42EMEBhvWQP5Cmt4RXFMKTZ7TXes0y/jT/l1 VF3evNuGI+RZCweUGVqzRWA3z+tV3qbVXuRKtNfXjGvhtG8RTX2SYwqvjDGsnR0XS8Gd1kGUGbeL fOE8vF3q5O2OiN5FF0xMg/0uEw2fZ3P9zONVLsT/A6kCAwEAAaOBiTCBhjAJBgNVHRMEAjAAMAsG A1UdDwQEAwIHgDAsBglghkgBhvhCAQ0EHxYdT3BlblNTTCBHZW5lcmF0ZWQgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUw HQYDVR0OBBYEFCc/oVSDFtH46U81hILH78cwLnR9MB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFLIkRa3EwPkvEabba+7h fY4FDjr9MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQB1TpQ66zJL+69iooqSQIryzLykWqcXeVeJOAWbGwbP x2P5LVboqXRxj5j9jmlTyqQLRoHLS5BaExq+P+2sPd/BOU2/QV9yrv7uAFkxyQjcMip8eqj1pc0X gqW+JoIkeeqa+UWj+fVQg/YqHsFNgkSoxCf4aPWC2x5X33SH6D8QkXQw4FJcRppfmr4ljsbPmuvV V1uk34I6PTb3gRlVIiTvUWtRaOLQ0lDlFa5bO5rd9nQV7UsK2e7ghXZpUtdW6OAYIuP3ASweOlE1 6z2DiMlYMGJ8Ci/vdcG1eEhVQoV0+z2s78ybJXelTiuxHvuJLPTNk5eoG5zAOAz8oFoQi+51
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:Object Id="Signature20257-data545881">
<xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"Target="#Signature-830342">
<xades:SignedProperties Id="SignedProperties-830342">
<xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
<xades:SigningTime>2014-07-08T12:40:02+02:00</xades:SigningTime>
<xades:SigningCertificate>
<xades:Cert>
<xades:CertDigest>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>ivK7JSJgkt1YHLuXeUphxagMGcI=</ds:DigestValue>
</xades:CertDigest>
</xades:Cert>
</xades:SigningCertificate>
<xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
<xades:SignaturePolicyId>
<xades:SigPolicyId>
<xades:Identifier>
http://www.facturae.es/politica_de_firma_formato_facturae/politica_de_firma_formato_facturae_v3_1.pdf
</xades:Identifier>
<xades:Description>facturae31</xades:Description>
</xades:SigPolicyId>
<xades:SigPolicyHash>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>Ohixl6upD6av8N7pEvDABhEL6hM=</ds:DigestValue>
</xades:SigPolicyHash>
</xades:SignaturePolicyId>
</xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
<xades:SignerRole>
<xades:ClaimedRoles>
<xades:ClaimedRole>supplier</xades:ClaimedRole>
</xades:ClaimedRoles>
</xades:SignerRole>
</xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
<xades:SignedDataObjectProperties/>
</xades:SignedProperties>
<xades:UnsignedProperties/>
</xades:QualifyingProperties>
</ds:Object>
</ds:Signature>
</note>
```

I need that namespace will be in the TAG Signature instead of the TAG Object

Comment: `XMLSignature signature; signature.sign(signContext);` should fail, shouldn't it

Comment: @mkl I don't understand what you mean. This is not failing right now. The signature method is involving the hash of the doc, put the references... and I need to set  the namespace in the middle of signature process

Comment: *I don't understand what you mean* - i meant to say that the code as present in your question calls `sign` of an unassigned variable. As it is not failing, i assume that you simply did not provide the assignment of the signature object.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but doesn't matter this assignment to solve the question.

Comment: Ok. Can you provide a sample signed document before and after that `addNamespace` call? Furthermore, which verifier gives you that *invalid signature error*?

Comment: Most likely @rzysia's answer is applicable. If you provided sample documents, that answer could be illustrated some more.

Comment: @mkl ok, I'm going to do it.

Comment: Can you also provide the XML after your `addNamespace` call? Because I don't necessarily see adding that nowhere used etsi namespace identifier changing signed information.

Comment: Is the same I added with the namespace in the signature TAG.The sign method of the Java API sign the domsigncontext, which generate, sign and marshall the signature tag, references and the doc to be signed.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are used to calculate hash value. Canonicalization shoud add them to document (additionally in alphabetical order).
Adding namespaces to signed document obviously will change its hash

Comment: Yes, but how can I add it with Canonicalization?

Comment: I'm using nu.xom.canonical.Canonicalizer, but it doesn't add namespaces - I'm doing it on my own (after canonicalization with xom). While doing this, you have to remember about canonicalization rules - ex. about alphabetical order added namespaces.
Best source about canonicalization is http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n, but this (http://www.di-mgt.com.au/xmldsig.html) was the most helpful for me